# AzDO Pipeline waiting for permission to agent pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We're using yaml pipelines with environment agents installed on local infrastructure. Each Environment is backed by a Deployment Pool which is implicitly created by AzDO. The pools reside at the org level.

Every time someone adds an environment to a pipeline it requires the project collection admin to authorize the pipeline. The devs cannot authorize the pipeline because they don't have permission at the org level. Image below shows prompt received.

Is there anyway to simplify this so the PCA is not required to authorize every on-prem pipeline?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we do not have any methods to skip the permit from PCA, when a pipeline is trying to target to an environment at the first time.

On the **Organization Settings** and **Project Settings**, we also do not have any built-in options to defaultly permit all new environments on all pipelines.

This is aiming to prevent the environments from being abused.

Comment: Thank you. I agree the environment should have to explicitly grant access to the pipeline. This can be done by a role within the project. It would be simpler if the pool which backs the an environment granted access to the implicit environment. Then the PCA wouldn't need to be involved.